# python configuring logging via yaml file

Tags: python, logging, pyyaml

I'm trying to configure logging for my app using a yaml file and `logging.config.dictConfig`, it's not really working, I don't think the configuration is being taken by the `logging`.

here's my yaml file:

```
  version: 1
  logging:
    disable_existing_loggers: true
    formatters:
      multi-process:
        class: logging.Formatter
        style:
        datefmt: "%I:%M:%S"
        format: "{levelname:8s}; {process:5d}; {asctime:s}; {name:<15s} {lineno:4d}; {message:s}"
      multi-thread:
        class: logging.Formatter
        style:
        datefmt: "%I:%M:%S"
        format: "{levelname:8s}; {threadName:5d}; {asctime:s}; {name:<15s} {lineno:4d}; {message:s}"
      verbose:
        class: logging.Formatter
        style:
        datefmt: "%I:%M:%S"
        format: "{levelname:8s}; {process:5d}; {threadName:8s}; {asctime:s}; {name:<15s} {lineno:4d}; {message:s}"
    handlers:
      console:
        level: DEBUG
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        formatter: verbose
        stream: ext://sys.stdout
      file_handler:
        level: INFO
        class: logging.handlers.WatchedFileHandler
        formatter: verbose
        filename: backtest.log
        mode: a
        encoding: utf-8
    loggers:
      example:
        level: DEBUG
        handlers: 
          - console
    root:
      handlers:
        - console
      level: DEBUG
```

here's how I load it:

```
with open('logging.yaml', 'r') as stream:
    yamld = yaml.load(stream)
    logging.config.dictConfig(yamld)

logger = logging.getLogger("example")

logger.debug('debug message')
logger.info('info message')
logger.warn('warn message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.critical('critical message')
```

this is my output to console:

```
warn message
error message
critical message
```

it's like my configurations aren't loaded at all

Comment: It is bad practice to use PyYAML's `load` (without `Loader` argument), `yaml.safe_load()` will do fine on this file so there is no excuse for not using that.

Answer (score 0):

got it, `logging` dict is not what the logging module looks for.

I just had to place my yaml plain, without `logging:`